# Synthetica swing theam doesn't load properly

Tags: java, swing, themes, look-and-feel

I am using Synthetica swing themes for an application, there is an option for the user which can be used to change the theme, though the theme applied I have to minimize or maximize the window to apply the theme properly. Could anyone tell me why is that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to change [Swing Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) on runtime, then [you have to call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic)

```
SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI(JFrame / JDialog / JWindow)
```